# Strange behaviors with ListContourPlot and ContourPlot: rotation relationship

Tags: plotting

Here is an example in `ListContourPlot`

```
ListContourPlot[Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, Pi, 0.1}, {j, 0, Pi, 0.1}], DataRange -> {{0, Pi}, {0, Pi}}]
```

Now, we only plot the contour for a specific value with `ContourPlot`, say, 0.6

```
ContourPlot[Sin[i + j^2] == 0.6, {i, 0, Pi}, {j, 0, Pi}]
```

The two commands yield left and right figures, respectively.

[image]

It can be found that they will become consistent after flipping the later with respect to its left-up to right-down diagonal.

My question is how can we get a consistent figure with `ContourPlot` in the sense of the contour shape. **It will be much better if someone could explain the strange behaviors** with `ListContourPlot` and `ContourPlot`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the `Table`, i is y (rows) and j is x (columns). In the other plot, i is x and j is y. It's just like this because when you construct matrices (rank 2 lists) you're actually building lists of lists.

Comment: The documentation for `ListContourPlot` states that "ListContourPlot[array] arranges successive rows of array up the page, and successive columns across." 

Since in your `ContourPlot` the "up the page" axis is the `j` axis, to get the same result with `ListContourPlot`, the rows, i.e., first index in `Table`, must be the `j` variable.

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you for your reply. Well, for `DataRange -> {{range1}, {range2}}` in `ListContourPlot`, do `{range1}` and `{range2}` correspond to "across  the page" and  "up the page", respectively? I have read the documentation, it seemes no explanation on this.

Comment: @user55777 - Yes. Look at `ListContourPlot[
 Table[i + j, {i, 0, 5, 0.1}, {j, 0, 10, 0.1}],
 DataRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 5}}]` to verify.

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of iterators in `ContourPlot`:

```
cp = ContourPlot[Sin[i + j^2] == 0.6, {j, 0, Pi}, {i, 0, Pi}, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

[image]

```
Show[ListContourPlot[Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, Pi, 0.1}, {j, 0, Pi, 0.1}], 
    DataRange -> {{0, Pi}, {0, Pi}}], cp]
```

[image]